# See the source of an video element

Tags: web-scraping

I want to get the raw video data. I tried to inspect it, but there isn't a src attribute.
normal page:

[The normal page](https://c418.bandcamp.com/track/stranger-think)

[A page with only a video element](https://t4.bcbits.com/stream/d46d1a63e396e2dfcdd16c6668216632/mp3-128/1123940537?p=0&ts=1655302451&t=ab14d80d4deaae68e3de07bf2b0edff698c83a5a&token=1655302451_27a75f9bc7ecfa6928c8fc005f0c451b95ed5217)

Answer (score 0):

you have to leftclick the element and the click something like save audio